# Bot Framework V4 - TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked

Tags: javascript, botframework

I am trying to make a rest query against a database that stores knowledge articles for users and returns an array of results based on what the user has searched for. Whenever I try to search I get:

> "TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked"

I have tried adding it to async as shown but I still keep getting the same error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
const Response = async (turnContext) => {
    if (turnContext.activity.value.choice === 'feedbackProvider') {
        try {
            const feedbackBody = turnContext.activity.value.feedbackBody;
            const feedbackEmail = turnContext.activity.value.feedbackEmail;
            storage.write(feedbackBody, feedbackEmail);
            await turnContext.sendActivity(`Feedback Sent`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('fetch failed', err);
        }
    } else if (turnContext.activity.value.choice === 'issueRaiser') {
        try {
            const bugTitle = turnContext.activity.value.issueTitle;
            const bugDesc = turnContext.activity.value.issueDescription;
            const bugEmail = turnContext.activity.value.issueEmail;
            const request = require('request');
            request({
                method: 'Post',
                uri: `<uri>issues?title=${ bugTitle }&description=${ bugDesc } ${ bugEmail }&labels=bug`,
                json: true,
                headers: {
                    'Private-Token': '<token>'
                }
            });
            turnContext.sendActivity(`Issue Raised`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('fetch failed', err);
        }
    } else if (turnContext.activity.value.choice === 'knowledgeBaseSearch') {
        try {
            const knowledgeBaseTopic = turnContext.activity.value.knowledgeBaseTopic;
            request({
                url: process.env.SN_KB_URL + knowledgeBaseTopic,
                json: true,
                auth: {
                    'username': process.env.Ticket_User,
                    'password': process.env.Ticket_Key
                }
            }, async (error, response, body) => {
                try {
                    var stuff = [];
                    for (var i = 0, len = body.result.length; i < len; i++) {
                        stuff.push(
                            CardFactory.heroCard(body.result[i].short_description, ['imageUrl1'], [`${ process.env.SN_KB_Resp_URl }${ body.result[i].number }`])

                        );
                    }
                    let messageWithCarouselOfCards = MessageFactory.carousel(stuff);
                    await turnContext.sendActivity(messageWithCarouselOfCards);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('fetch failed', err);
        }
    }
};
```

Full Error Message:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
cardMiddleware.js:35
    at Request.request [as _callback] (c:\Bots\sdk4-2\skills\cardMiddleware.js:35:45)
    at Request.self.callback (c:\Bots\sdk4-2\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (c:\Bots\sdk4-2\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Bots\sdk4-2\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
```

From my post on the forum I was informed that I was using a request module that did not support Promises, which I believe was causing my error. I've now began to use Axios for my request which is shown below;

```
try {
    return await axios.get(process.env.SN_KB_URL + knowledgeBaseTopic, {
        headers: {
          auth: {
          username: process.env.Ticket_User,
          password: process.env.Ticket_Key
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

However now when I run the request I get a 401 'Unauthorised' error and I'm not sure what is wrong with my request.

Comment: This is especially curious considering that you're only doing a post and not a get, and your code doesn't mention any proxies. Can you figure out which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi @Mark! I got this exact same error today, and am going to track down someone who can help with it. As soon as I have the solution, I'll post it!

Comment: Mark, can you post the rest of the error you're getting?

Comment: @KyleDelaney The error appears on line 49. Its when this elseif starts turnContext.activity.value.choice === 'knowledgeBaseSearch' everything else works.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I've updated the post with the full error message that I'm getting.

Comment: @MarkWeir: While tracking down a solution, the daily release of the botbuilder packages on the myget feed seems to have resolved it. Can you do a test build using the myget package 4.1.5? [Myget daily JS build](https://botbuilder.myget.org/feed/botbuilder-v4-js-daily/package/npm/botbuilder/4.1.5)

Comment: @MarkWeir - Is this your question? https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/606

Comment: @KyleDelaney - Yes that's my question.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I've updated the package but I'm still getting the same error. I'm going to try and use a different request module as I don't believe my current request module supports promises (https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-requests-node-js-async-await/)

Comment: @MarkWeir - Are there any updates?

Comment: @KyleDelaneyI've started to use Axios for my request as the old module that I was using didn't support promises. I'm no longer getting the revoked proxy error but now my request is getting a 401 unauthorised error, and I'm not sure what im doing wrong with the auth on my request. I've updated the post to show this new error and my request.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to consider this question answered so that other people can see what causes the revoked proxy error, and then ask a new question about the unauthorized error. Would you like me to post an answer for you to accept or would you like to post the answer yourself?

Comment: Good idea @KyleDelaney I've marked this question as complete and have opened this new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448900/typeerror-cannot-read-property-data-of-undefined

Comment: maybe `turnContext.sendActivity(`Issue Raised`);` needs `await`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue happened because I was using a request module that did not support promises. Changing my request module for one that did support promises (which I found out about by using [this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-requests-node-js-async-await/)) resolved the issue.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 5):

The answer for me was to double check I didn't miss any `await` usage that might be necessary. Turns out I called `this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);` without the `await` and that threw the same error. I found the answer on [this Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/168)

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time struggling with this issue. As other commenters have noted, the issue lies in the fact that the Lex Runtime is not promise-based, so you cannot await requests, which causes the proxy to be revoked.

Here is my solution:

```
async callLex(context) {
    const params = {
        botAlias: 'prod',
        botName: 'botName',
        userId: context.activity.from.id,
        contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        accept: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        inputStream: context.activity.text.trim()
    }
    let request = lexruntime.postContent(params)
    await request.promise().then(
        async response => {
            console.log(response)
            console.log('Success!')
            await context.sendActivity(response.message)          
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log('Error!')
        })
}
```

Rather than directly invoke the request like "lexruntime.postContent(params, callback func)", I exclude the callback function and utilize the "promise" property of AWS.Request to send the request as a promise which enables me to use "await" and keeps the proxy open. [See documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put this here only because it's the first result that pops up when searching, although it doesn't directly relate to this issue.

**There's a very easy way to use `setTimeout()` and avoid this error:**

```js
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(
    turnContext.sendActivity('I was sent 5 seconds later')
), 5000));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, we were trying to upload files from a Task Module (modal popup of teams) to the bot and in response the bot would give a first confirmation that the attachments are uploading. This activity would close the task module (as the bot must reply within 10 seconds or teams would resend the request). Now when the attachments were uploaded, we wanted to update the previously sent adaptive card with the list of the uploaded attachments. We achieved this using the proactive messaging feature of bot framework.

```
const conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(activity);
Promise.all(listOfPromises).then(() => {
    await botAdapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity('All attachments uploaded!');
    });
}
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Answer (score 0):

Check for lines that needs `await` inside any aync function.  I hope that azure will point usto which file or line specifically but I have not figured it out until I looked at all my functions.

Okay, so this is indeed a very cryptic error message as the github thread [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/168) suggested .

But I found that I was not `await` ing in this block:

```js
    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {.
      const didBotWelcomedUser = await this.welcomedUserProperty.get(
        context,
        "false"
      );  

      if (didBotWelcomedUser === false) {
        // first time user is in chat
        await this.sendWelcomeMessage(context); `<-------- await here was missing`
      } else {
        await this.sendSuggestedAction(context); `<-------- await here was missing`
      }



      await next();
    });

    this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {


      await this.sendWelcomeMessage(context);
      await next();
    });
  }
```

I thought `await.next()` is enough.  We all gotta learn this somehow... Hope you resolve yours.